# What song has the most *distinct* words in the lyrics?

Tags: lyrics

I see that "Rap God" by Eminem is generally credited as the hit song with the most (1560) words in the lyrics, and one or two other less-known songs (such as "Animal" by Harry Shotta with 1771 and "La Cátedra" by "Residente" Rene Perez with 1900) exceeding Eminem.

But what song has the most *distinct* words in its lyrics, that is, words left after eliminating duplicated words?

Example: the song "Let X = X" by Laurie Anderson has 216 words of ordinary lyrics, plus around 900 repeated samples of the word "ha" as part of the rhythm track – but only 114 words (including the "ha") after eliminating duplicated words.